# recent upgrade to joomla 3.2 will not save configuration parameters

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I am trying to save a simple setting in K2 parameters (Use one editor window for introtext & fulltext) and every time I hit the save button it reverts to my previous setting? Any ideas?

EDIT:

It appears that this in not a bug exclusive to K2 for me. It is not allowing me to change parameters in other components either. example: i just tried to change the article configuration for "show title" to "hide" and the same behavior was observed.

When saving I receive a green box stating it has been saved, but it still reverts to the old setting.

Comment: It might be a bug for Joomla 3.2 and K2. Might be best you post a comment on the K2 forum

Comment: I'm building 2 J3.2 sites with K2 now and have not encountered this. Please give more detail about your scenario.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks for confirming that. Destination Designs, it must be a problem on your side then. What version of PHP / MySQL are you using? Are you using the stable release of Joomla 3.2 rather than the alpha or beta? Have you touched any of the core K2 code? or even core Joomla code for that matter?

Comment: I haven't really confirmed anything. I just haven't seen it. However, I still don't know what you're trying to configure, exactly. Explain it and I'll do a test.

Comment: The details are pretty simple. When I attempt to change a setting in K2 parameters and hit "save" or "save & close" the setting does not change to the new setting. This is confirmed when changing the setting (Use one editor window for introtext & fulltext). I even looked in the item editor to see if the change had saved but not the button in parameters. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I updated to 3.2 through the joomla update manager so it is the 3.2.0 stable release. My version of PHP is 5.3.26 and MySQL version is 5.5.32

Comment: I was able to successfully change 'K2 default CSS' and 'jQuery library handling' in J3.2.0/K2 2.6.7. I did get a 404 when I cancelled out of Parameters, though, but it doesn't seem to cause a problem.

Comment: It appears that this in not a bug exclusive to K2 for me. It is not allowing me to change parameters in other components either. example: i just tried to change the article configuration for "show title" to "hide" and the same behavior was observed.

Comment: PHP errors? JS errors?

Comment: none, i have error reporting set to maximum and i checked the console from chromes's inspect element tool.

Comment: Do you have magic quotez turned on or off?

Comment: turns out this was an issue of caching being turned on.